# how to trigger major compaction for hbase through the java

Tags: java, hbase

I want to add a task to my server scheduler to run a major compaction for the hbase.
How can I implement this with java code?

It could be either for single region or for all regions.
Can I do the major compaction for some specific tablespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
String tableName = "mytable";
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.addResource(new Path("/home/user/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));

HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
admin.majorCompact(tableName);
...
```

If a table name is given then the compaction will be invoked on all regions of that table.
Refer to the [majorCompact javadoc](http://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#majorCompact%28java.lang.String%29):

After invoking this code you'll find the note "*Compacting stores...*" under *"Currently running tasks"* on the **Master UI** (port 60010 by default)